# When *.pyc files (related to their deb-packages) are created and how to recreate them?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, python, gobject

I have two Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS systems:

1. clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
2. upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

**Note:** All things in the both systems have been installed using APT (from *deb*-packages). I did not use `pip`/`pip3`, `make install`, `checkinstall` and other similar utilities. So it is absolutely on topic. It is Ubuntu, Ubuntu uses APT.

First system have the following `pyc`-files:

- `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Dee.pyc`
- `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/__pycache__/Dee.cpython-36.pyc`
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Unity.pyc`
- `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/__pycache__/Unity.cpython-36.pyc`

Second system do not have these files.

I can not find packages for these files with `dpkg -S`. But I can find for scripts (`*.py`).

As far I can understand these files came from `gir1.2-dee-1.0` and `gir1.2-unity-5.0`.
But after re-installation of these packages the `*.pyc` files are not created.

What is wrong?
How to get `*.pyc` in their places? Will my system work normally without these files?

Comment: Thank you, @Melebius. Could you please read my post carefully? I write this question for deb-packaged things. I think I do not need broad Python answers here :) I'm waiting for APT-based (deb postist or something similar) answers and comments.

Comment: OK, I’ve made an answer for you.

Comment: @Melebius while I was making mine hmm? :D

Comment: @Rinzwind You hadn’t told. :D However, your answer is more detailed than mine, so upvote awarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm waiting for APT-based

It is not related to APT so that is going to take some time ;-)

> What is wrong?

Nothing.

> How to get *.pyc in their places?

If you really want to you could do it manually with [py_compile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/py_compile.html).  From the python command line (replace {pyfile.py} for the one you want compiled):

```
>>> import py_compile
>>> py_compile.compile('{pyfile.py}')
```

There is also a command line method that allows to compile all in a directory with ...

```
python -m compileall .
```

There is not really a need to do so though: these get created *as you use software on your machine*. That is also why this has no relation to APT.

> Will my system work normally without these files?

Yes.

What actually happens: when a module is imported or when the source was changed, a `.pyc` file containing the compiled code will be created in the same directory as the `.py file`. This file is used to skip the compilation step for that module. Shaves of a few milliseconds on execution (not important for normal usages but imagine a webserver calling the same script 1000s of times within a seconds. Those milliseconds suddenly become important).

Regarding not seeing a `.pyc` file somewhere:

There are times when python can not compile. 1 example would be if you use a 2nd user that is not allowed to create a file in the location the compilation would be stored. Execution will not stop and then will  use the source (and not the compiled version) (Running a script is not considered an import; this is only done for modules).

Answer (score 2):

The `*.pyc` files contain Python [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode). They are created when the corresponding `*.py` file is executed for the first time (and updated on the first run after the corresponding `*.py` changes).

Since the Python interpreter on your machine is able to create the `*.pyc` files and is good in creating them on-the-fly, **the `*.pyc` files are not included in the APT repositories.** They are just generated on your machine from the corresponding `*.py` files – which are included.

As a result, the machine used for a longer time and having been running more applications will likely contain more `*.pyc` files than a clean OS installation unless you clean up those files.

See also:

- [If Python is interpreted, what are .pyc files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2998215/711006)
- ["Compiled" Python files](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/CompiledPythonfiles.html)
- [Difference between .py and .pyc files?](http://net-informations.com/python/iq/pyc.htm)